# Supabase API in Flutter

Tags: supabase, supabase-flutter

I am new to using Supabase and working with api in general. Does using CRUD operations with api on Supabase affects my bandwidth of 5gb in the free plan?

Like can I read data from my table using the api? and if so, will it affect the 5gb of the free plan?

Comment: Yes, any outgoing traffic counts towards your 5gb free plan bandwidth.